# Random number inside regular polygon

Tags: r

I need to generate `n` points inside of n-gon distributed uniformly. Additionally, I want to store in matrix `nx2`.

Comment: Please add what you have already attempted. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `spsample` in `sp` package:

```
library(sp)

pol <- matrix(c(0 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,2 ,2 ,0 , 2, 0, 0), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
pol <- Polygon(pol)
spsample(pol, 100, type = "random")
```

Example:

```
pol <- matrix(c(5 ,1.5 ,1 ,8 ,3 ,12 ,8 , 10, 14, 5), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
pol <- Polygon(pol)
s <- spsample(pol, 1000, type = "random")
pol@coords %>% as.data.frame() %>% set_names(c("x", "y")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_polygon(color = "black") + 
  geom_point(data = s@coords %>% data.frame() %>% set_names(c("x", "y")), colour = "white")
```

[image]